# How to pull MAC addresses per vlan using SNMPv3 from cisco switch?

Tags: snmp, cisco, pysnmp, vlan

I want to pull all the MAC addresses that the switch knows about. I found in SNMPv2

This command is successful from a linux terminal

```
snmpwalk -v2c  -c SNMPCommunity@10 10.10.10.10 .1.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3.1.1
```

This command needs to have the "@10" inserted but I have no idea where.

```
snmpwalk -v3  -l authPriv -u username -a SHA -A authpriv  -x DES -X authkey 10.10.10.10 .1.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3.1.1
```

The above command only pulls MAC addresses from VLAN1. I tried username@10 - but then I get bad username

Big picture. I'm trying to pull them with a python script using pysnmp. I got everything working but this last part.

Comment: I'm getting closer. I added "snmp-server group snmpgroupname v3 auth context vlan- match prefix" to the cisco config. Now I can get a vlan mac return from "snmpwalk -v 3 -l authPriv -u testUser -a MD5 -A testv3 -x 3DES -X testpriv3DES –n vlan-10 <IPAddress> <OID>" yay - my question is answered, but I can't get pysnmp to pass the contextname. Maybe that's a different question.

Comment: Your question is tagged pysnmp but your examples are for Net-SNMP from the command line. Which are you actually using?

Comment: oops. I can't post the pysnmp code in the comment box (too long)  but I have crossposted the questoion here https://github.com/etingof/pysnmp/issues/284

Comment: Construct then post a [mcve]. And put it in the question, not in the comments.

Comment: @Dwight, I am trying to do the same thing, but adding Contextname is not returning anything, how did you get yours done?

Comment: @ahmad_r According to my comment on the answer "below" I added  ContextData(contextName='vlan-10'). I think this was on Cisco 3850 switches, probably running 15.2 code or similar.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67115981/pysnmp-pulling-mac-address-table-per-vlan-on-cisco-switch-with-snmpv3 ---- I have done what you did but i am getting error, i have posted the question on the link. i am not sure what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

To get pysnmp using non-default SNMP context name, just pass your context name in form of [ContextName](http://snmplabs.com/pysnmp/docs/api-reference.html#snmp-context) object as [contextData](http://snmplabs.com/pysnmp/docs/hlapi/asyncore/sync/manager/cmdgen/nextcmd.html#getnext-command) parameter to `nextCmd()`.

```
from pysnmp.hlapi import *

errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(
    getCmd(SnmpEngine(),
           UsmUserData('usr-md5-des', 'authkey1', 'privkey1'),
           UdpTransportTarget(('demo.snmplabs.com', 161)),
           ContextData(contextName='vlan-10'),
           ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('1.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3.1.1')))
)
```

Comment: That didn't work but this did - thanks for you help
    `ContextData(contextName='vlan-10')`